# Как сохранить вектор инициализации (iv) в файл при шифровании AES-CBC?

Tags: node.js, шифрование

Как известно - `AES-CBC` требует `iv` вектор, который не является секретной информацией. Когда шифруют текст, его, обычно, дописывают к зашифрованным данным.

Сейчас возникла необходимость на node js шифровать определенные файлы. Я конечно могу вписать `iv` вектор в имя файла, но хотелось бы добавлять его к зашифрованному блобу (картинке).

Как такое сделать? Хрнаить `iv` в начале файла, или в конце? Использовать ли `HMAC` для аутентификации?

P.S
(Для чтения и записи использую потоки); Также сложность в том, что используются потоки: загрузка из интернета, оптимизация картинки, подсчет хеш-суммы, запись на диск.

Comment: Вроде его всегда хранят в начале, что довольно логично. Он же нужен что  бы начать расшифровку, т.е. можно параллельно читать (получать по сети) файл и расшифровывать его, а не ждать когда он весь прочитается (скачается).

Comment: Звучит логично! А импользутся ли hmac при шифровании файлов? Ну, во избежание этого: https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2002/23320530/cbc02_e02d.pdf

Comment: А это зависит от чего вы защищаетесь. В частности, в описанной атаке есть сервер которому можно «задавать вопросы», а если у вас просто лежит файл на диске, то это неактуально.  С другой стороны, это всего-лишь несколько лишних байт.